# missing FROM-clause entry for table when using string_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query to try to search for the course that fulfills 3 requirements.

```
select
    course.id,
    course.title,
    course.number,
    string_agg(requirement.description,'; ' order by requirement.description) 
from course
join
(
    select course.id, course.title, course.number
    from requirement join course_requirement 
        on (requirement.id=course_requirement.requirement)
    join course on (course.id=course_requirement.course) 
    where requirement.description='Human Behavior'
) as c1
    on (c1.id=course.id)
join
(
    select course.id, course.title, course.number 
    from requirement
    join course_requirement
        on (requirement.id=course_requirement.requirement)
    join course
        on (course.id=course_requirement.course) 
    where requirement.description='Intercultural'
) as c2
    on (c1.id=c2.id)
join
(
    select course.id, course.title, course.number 
    from requirement
    join course_requirement
        on (requirement.id=course_requirement.requirement)
    join course
        on (course.id=course_requirement.course) 
    where requirement.description='Religion'
) as c3
    on (c1.id=c3.id)
group by course.id, course.title, course.number;
```

However, I receive this message: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "requirement"
LINE 1: ...course.id, course.title, course.number,string_agg(requiremen...
Can you tell me where did I get the query wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: After editing your query, the cause of the error seems clear: You are aggregating `requirement.description` but there is no such alias/table `requirement` in the outer query.

Comment: In your `SELECT` area you're referencing `requirement.description`, but there is no table named `requirement` - the only tables in scope are `course`, `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I did not see that! I got the code fixed by including the requirements table and it works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of the three joined subqueries, which differ only in the requirement description in the `WHERE` clause.  Instead, you might try a single query which uses `WHERE IN` to capture the three descriptions you want in your result set.  This also fixes the problem you had with `string_agg()`, where you were trying to aggregate something from a subquery not reachable in the outer query.

Try the following query:

```
select
    t1.id,
    t1.title,
    t1.number,
    string_agg(t3.description, '; ' order by t3.description) 
from course t1
inner join course_requirement t2
    on t1.id = t2.course
inner join requirement t3
    on t2.requirement = t3.id
where t3.description in ('Human Behavior', 'Intercultural', 'Religion')
group by t1.id, t1.title, t1.number;
```